# Datatables PDF export right to left

Tags: datatable, datatables

I've managed to make a new font and add it to the datatable, but when I generated the PDF the text was aligned from left to right which is the opposite of what I wants, is there any configurations that I could use to make is right to left.
Also I'm using server side processing, and multi-column filtering, and the PDF button only prints the current page, what is the configuration to make it print the whole filter result.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use specific pdfmake configuration options to manipulate the exported PDF:
https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdfHtml5

This will make the text to align right, it won't make the text run from right-to-left, however:

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'pdf',
    customize: function ( doc ) {
      doc.content[0].alignment = 'right';
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @lofihelsinki but the issue that I'm having is that the text is aligned in a left to right format
(direction opposite the in English writing imagine)
so is there a fix to this problem ?, even a function that will reverse the words till the final solution comes
Thanks in advance

Comment: rtl-text seems to be missing from pdfmake, there is a ticket [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/184). The only option would be to loop all the rows and cells in the table and reverse each text individually, like `str.split("").reverse()`. The tables rows are usually in `doc.content[n].table.body` where `n` might be 1 or 2 depending on other content you have before the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

hi here is my code for persian ltr to rtl this is a function that's can use in datatable to export as pdf :

```
function buttonForDatatable(columns, margins, prtrait = "portrait",title='',message='') {
            return [
                 {
            extend: 'copy',
            text:"کپی",
            exportOptions: {

                columns: columns.reverse(),

            },

        },  {
            extend: 'csv',
            text:"سی اس وی",
            exportOptions: {

                columns: columns.reverse(),

            },

        },  {
            extend: 'print',
            text:"پرینت",
            exportOptions: {

                columns: columns.reverse(),

            },

        }, {
            extend: 'excel',
            text:"اکسل",
            exportOptions: {

                columns: columns,

            },

        }  ,{
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: prtrait,
                    footer: true,
                    alignment: "center",
                    title: title,
                    messageTop:message,
                    text: "PDF",
                    exportOptions: {
                        alignment: "center",
                        orthogonal: "PDF",
                        columns: columns,
                        modifier: {order: 'index', page: 'current'}

                    },
                    customize: function (doc) {
                        doc.styles.message.alignment = "right";
                        doc.styles.tableBodyEven.alignment = "center";
                        doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.alignment = "center";
                        doc.styles.tableFooter.alignment = "center";
                        doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = "center";
                        doc.content[0]['text'] = doc.content[0]['text'].split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
                        doc.content[1].margin = margins;
                        doc.content[2].margin = margins;
                        for (var i = 0; i < doc.content[2].table.body.length; i++) {
                            // console.log(doc.content[1].table.body[i].length);
                            for (var j = 0; j < doc.content[2].table.body[i].length; j++) {
                                doc.content[2].table.body[i][j]['text'] = doc.content[2].table.body[i][j]['text'].split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ];
        }
```

and after that you are can use same as here :

```
 table = $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
                language: language,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "all"]],
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                buttons: buttonForDatatable([2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0]),
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
.....
```